# CentOS7 packets disappear after PREROUTING

Tags: iptables, routing

Packets are disappearing while trying to get them forwarded to libvirt machines.

The incoming requests hit my interface / public IP

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  165  8580 DNAT       tcp  --  em4    *       0.0.0.0/0            50.x.y.z            tcp dpt:80 to:192.168.122.100
...

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      em4     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
...
```

And I have the rules on both FORWARD and OUTPUT to match, both with no hits.

```
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.122.100      tcp dpt:80
...

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.122.100      tcp dpt:80
...
```

Forwarding is enabled for all interfaces:

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.em4.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.virbr0.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.vnet5.forwarding = 1
```

I believe routing is correct, I can hit the endpoint properly from my host

```
# ip route get 192.168.122.100
192.168.122.100 dev virbr0 src 192.168.122.1 uid 0
    cache

# curl --head http://192.168.122.100/
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
...
```

I have complete rule chains, including all default *libvirt* rules. The chains all end with LOG / DROP at the end, but nothing related ever hits those. I have been using `tcpdump` across all interfaces, I see the *syn* packets from the request which are the packets seen in the initial PREROUTING rule, but then nothing.

```
# uname -r
5.5.10-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
```

Where else could these packets be going after the PREROUTING rule? Is there something I've missed?

---

*edit*

Gerrit led me to look at the `rp_filter` which appears to be dropping my packets. I do have MASQUERADE rules, but it looks like they might be wrong.

```
kernel: IPv4: martian source 192.168.122.100 from 24.xx.yy.zz, on dev em4
kernel: ll header: 00000000: 78 2b cb 34 d5 70 98 52 4a 60 53 5d 08 00        x+.4.p.RJ`S]..
```

Answer (score 1):

The incoming packets are dropped by the rp_filter on em4 because of the way the routing is split over multiple interface aliases on this interface.

Usually with a DNAT rule, the reply packet NAT'ing should automatically be reversed on its way out so that the answer would seem to come from the interface where the DNAT was activated. This does not seem to function here, and the rp_filter indicates it sees the unmangled source address in the reply packet (This turns out to be caused by the DNAT, it confuses the kernel message).

Or the actual incoming packet IS a martian somehow, and your system has a different route to it then the interface where it comes in, and it is the kernel log message that is confusing because of the DNAT (There is indication that this message indeed shows the wrong address being called a martian when DNAT is involved).

Basically if `ip route get address/32` is not equal to the incoming interface then the packet is a Martian! You can also use loose rp filtering (setting of 2) to only filter if the address is not anywhere on the machine. Or you can set static routes yourself to unmartian those martians.

In iptables you cannot use interface aliases like em0:2 or something. It will only accept the main device.

Comment: Hmm, I do MASQUERADE rules, but it looks like they might be wrong. You led me to the `rp_filter` which, after enabling logging, is what appears to be dropping my packets. Still need to do more debugging.

Comment: I added the logs from `rp_filter` and my MASQUERADE rules.

Comment: Could you try this SNAT rule I edited just now. The general masquerade all outgoing packets rule on em4 you show would only be needed if you have lan packets on other interfaces that you want to route to outside.

Comment: `-t SNAT` should be `-j SNAT`, and `-i` is not a valid argument in the POSTROUTING table. Packets are moving if I disable the `rp_filter`.

Comment: Sorry, to hasty.

Comment: Even with the SNAT in place, I am getting drops on the `rp_filter`, before they get to the POSTROUTING table.

Comment: Do you get any nf_conntrack: table full errors in the kernel log?

Comment: Are there any additional rules in iptables raw or mangle?

Comment: Is mangle another table? Unfamiliar, will need to see if libvirt added something there I am unaware of. What would constitute an actual Martian packet? My setup may be strange, I am behind a Comcast router with a static IP block. `em4` is DHCP as 10.1.10.14, and `em4:0`, `em4:1`, and `em4:2` are virtual interfaces assigned the static public address 50.x.y.z This seems to work as using tcpdump I see the packets for the WAN addresses as expected.

Comment: With rp_filter=1 the source address received incoming on an in interface should be in a range that would be also sent to that same interface, otherwise it is called a martian.  If the DNAT rule is on em4, but the response would go through one of it is aliases, then this is probably the reason the rp_filter cuts in.

Comment: Does the DHCP server set a default gateway?